# overlay two images/links (html)

Tags: html, css

I would like to overlay two images, each one being a link (href) to another page. 
For instance I have a list of items (images) on which I can click to have more information, and **on** each images I want to put a "compare" button that would send me to another view. (I don't want a button near the image of the item, but **over** this image)

Comment: Please provide code showing what you have attempted so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
*
{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
div
{
  margin: 10px auto 0 auto;
  width: 150px;
  position: relative;
}
img
{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  background: #ccc;
}
button
{
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img alt="Image" />
  <button>Button</button>
</div>
```